# JS Doc comment link method

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

In JavaScript comments, I want to mention a method present in some file. How can I link to that method in comment? Eg.

Say my method is:

```
function xyz() {
}
```

and say I am writing a comment like

```
// See also {method-link to xyz}
```

What should {method-link} be?

Answer (score 23):

To link to "something else" in JSDoc, including another method, use the [`{@link ...}`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-inline-link.html) tag. In your case, you would use:

```js
// See also {@link xyz}
```

You'll then be able to Ctrl+click on `xyz` in WebStorm.

The JSDoc terminology for that "something else" is "namepath". Below follows the original answer by Andrew, which explains namepaths.

---

## [JSDoc3](https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths.html) styles:

### Basic Syntax Examples of Namepaths in JSDoc 3

```
myFunction
MyConstructor
MyConstructor#instanceMember
MyConstructor.staticMember
MyConstructor~innerMember // note that JSDoc 2 uses a dash
```

### Special cases: modules, externals and events.

```
/** A module. Its name is module:foo/bar.
 * @module foo/bar
 */

/** The built in string object. Its name is       external:String.
 * @external String
 */

 /** An event. Its name is module:foo/bar.event:MyEvent.
 * @event module:foo/bar.event:MyEvent
 */
```

## For easy coding, I sometime use `markdown` style in comment:

```
// see function name in file dir/file.name

// see the method [named of the method](file-name #method name)
```

Comment: So, for my example, putting xyz as it is should be fine. But why it does not become link like on pressing command. I am trying on webstorm.

Comment: @Chacha: I've added at the top of the answer how to actually link to methods.